# Is it possible to create a full-screen UIImagePickerController (with camera source) on an iPad 2?

Tags: camera, uiimagepickercontroller, ipad-2

My goal seems simple: Replicate the behavior of the iPad 2 camera app with regard to previewing/taking still photos.  Namely, I want to display the preview in a full-screen window.

Unfortunately this seems impossible on the iPad 2 with a UIImagePickerController.  A UIImagePickerController must be hosted within a UIPopoverController, and according to the docs:

> When changing the size of the popover’s content, the width value you specify must be at least 320 points and no more than 600 points.

This is fairly consistent with the results I've been seeing.  Regardless of the size I specify, I see a small preview window.  Is there a way to get around this with the UIImagePickerController?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs are confusing/wrong on this.  You can also present the camera full screen using a navigation controller with presentModalViewController.  This is exactly the same as on iPhone.

Note, this only works on a device, not on the simulator.

Comment: Hi Michael , Thanks for pointing out and providing the solution for capturing it in full screen mode. It works for me in ipad, but my only concern whether this approach will cause any issue while application review from apple, since we are not initiating the camera from the pop over and deviating from the apple docs.  Thanks again.